# Why is the Set-MailContact -EmailAddresses line in this returning an error?

Tags: powershell, csv, office365

As you can see from the screenshot, I get an error from running the script but when I take the output from `Write-Host` and paste it in, it runs successfully, what's going on?

For testing I commented out `New-Mailcontact` and added the `Write-Host` at the end.

```
$CSVpath = Read-Host -Prompt "Enter the path of the contacts .csv"
Import-Csv "$CSVpath" | ForEach-Object {
        $name = $_.displayName
        $proxies = $_.proxyAddresses
        $proxy = $proxies.replace(";",",")
        #New-MailContact -ExternalEmailAddress $_.Mail -Name "`"$name`"" -Alias $_.sAMAccountName -DisplayName $name -FirstName $_.givenName -Initials $_.initials -LastName $_.sn
        Set-MailContact -Identity $_.sAMAccountName -CustomAttribute1 "CreatedWithScript"
        Set-MailContact -Identity $_.sAMAccountName -CustomAttribute3 $_.extensionAttribute3 
        Set-MailContact -Identity $_.sAMAccountName -EmailAddresses $proxy
        Write-Host "New contact created: Name="$_.displayName 
        Write-Host "                     UPN="$_.userPrincipalName
        Write-Host Set-MailContact -Identity $_.sAMAccountName -EmailAddresses $proxy
        }
```

[image: ISE Screenshot]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Got the following which worked from a Spiceworks user.

> I think the -EmailAddresses parameter requires an array of strings
>   rather than a single comma separated string. Give it a try with this:
>
> `$proxy = $proxies -split ';'`
>
> `Set-MailContact -Identity $_.sAMAccountName -EmailAddresses $proxy`